# Подпрограммы в Pascal

Tags: pascal

Давным давно не писал в паскале, вот задал функцию и не могу найти ошибку.

```
program _1;
uses crt;
var
y:text;
minSumEl,n,g:real;
i,j,k:integer;
f:array[1..6,1..7] of real;
m:array[2..13] of real;
function OpMiSuElDi(m:array[2..13] of real;i,j,k:integer;f:array[1..6,1..7] of real):real;
for k:=2 to 13 do begin      
    m[k]:=0;
    for i:=1 to 6 do begin
        for j:=1 to 7 do begin
            if i+j=k then m[k]:=m[k]+f[i,j];
        end;
    end;
    if m[k]<result then
        result:=m[k];
end;                      
begin
    clrscr;
    assign(y,'file.dat');
    reset(y);
    g:=0;
    for i:=1 to 6 do begin
        for j:=1 to 7 do begin
            read(y,f[i,j]);
            write(f[i,j]:4:0);
        end;
        writeln;
    end;
    minSumEl:=OpMiSuElDi();;
    writeln('min summa elementov diagonali=',minSumEl:4:0);
    writeln(' ');
    for i:=1 to 6 do begin        
        for j:=1 to 7 do begin
            n:=f[i,j]/3;
            if (g=0) and (f[i,j]<0) and (frac(n)=0) then
            begin
                g:=i;
                writeln('otrizatelny element kratny 3 v ',i,' stroke');
            end;                          
        end;
    end;
    readkey;
end.
```

Comment: что компилятор говорит?

Comment: сделайте человеческий для чтения стиль

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Функция определена с аргументами, а вызывается без них. Я думаю, в данном случае определение аргументов вообще не нужно, т.к. "аргументы" уже определены как глобальные переменные.
2. Нет begin после определения функции (не забудьте добавить парный ему end в конце функции)
3. Не определен и не инициализирован result, + его значение не выводится из функции

Answer (score 1):

Вы не определили переменную `result` в теле функции, но обращаетесь к ней.

Если это Delphi, то функция возвращает результат через `result:=`, а в простом Pascal нужно присваивать "названию функции" `OpMiSuElDi:=`